# CSS result displaying differently in browsers

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a HTML page with some data in span. I tried to align the contents in the span. It is working fine in chrome, but when coming to FireFox, it is displaying differently.

**HTML**

```
<div class="header" id="header">
<span class="totalTime">Status: (Worked/Total) - 23/38</span>
<span class="effeciency">Effeciency : 15.05</span>
<span class="links">
   <span class="casesLink"><a href="index.jsp">Allocated Cases</a></span>
   <span class="reportsLinks"><a href="UsersCounts.jsp">User Counts</a></span></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0em;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    background: #ff8800;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

span.totalTime {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
}

span.effeciency {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 2em;
    top: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

span.links {
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.links>span {
    display: inline-table;
    padding: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 0em;
    padding-top: 0em;
}
```

I've created a fiddle and can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pwg69xxu/1/).

Here is the working fiddle full screen output. To see the correct result, paste this in both Chrome and Firefox Browsers.

https://jsfiddle.net/pwg69xxu/1/embedded/result/

Comment: OMG! Flex mixed with inline-table mixed with floats.... It's normal that its behaviour is different. You have a `flex` item with 200px width. It doesn't fits. Chrome shrink the inline-table, but firefox is working fine. Just add more width to this element and it works (270 pixels is sufficient for my screen). However, you must to learn layout to avoid this kind of things (flex + float + table, weird way)

Comment: Your code has many css wrong code you can reduce the css to style what you have in your html , if you want i can make it for you :)

Comment: Hi @ahmdabos, Yes please, it would be very helpful. Thank you

Comment: Hi @MarcosPérezGude, My Bad, sorry. I've searched it online and used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add code below to prevent strings from wrapping to another line:

```
span.links a
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the updated code, now you can work on it without facing issues:

```
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    background: #ff8800;
    padding: 20 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;

}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 31%;
    margin-left: 13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fff;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 33%;
    margin-right: 13px;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fff;
}
.center {
    float: left;
    width: 32%;
}
.header ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 18px auto;
}
.header ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
</style>
<div class="header">
<div class="left"><p>Status: (Worked/Total) - 23/38</p></div>
<div class="center">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.jsp">Allocated Cases</a></li>
<li><a href="UsersCounts.jsp">User Counts</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="right"><p>Effeciency : 15.05</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
span.links {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/pwg69xxu/2/)**

because you set `width` for `span.links`. I removed and give it `100% width` and `text-align: center` and also `display: inline-block`. now it works on all major browser such Chrome or FF.